ROS Client remote access to server remote network
SETUP:
  .---------.      .------.           .---------.
  | Server: |______| Jump |___ ... ___| Client  |
  | ROS     |      | Host |           |         |
  '---------'      '------'           '---------'

'Jump Host' and 'Server' can be reached password-less, i.e.
certificates have been applied to log onto the 'Server' from
the 'Client. Running rostopic list  and rostopic info $topic for each
topic in the list delivers the name of the server and several
ports, e.g.
 the-server 4711   # i.e. port 4711 on the-server
 the-server 42     # i.e. port 42 ...

From the client side, tunnels are created with
 > ssh -f -N -L $port:localhost:$port user@the-server

for each port in 4711, 42, and 11311. Port 11311 is the ROS
master port which is also announced through the environment variable
ROS_MASTER_URI:
 export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

Also, the-server is listed in /etc/hosts:
 127.0.0.1    the-server

On both sides, Client and Server /.../ros/.../setup.bash
has been sourced.
On the remote Server machine, everything works properly. That is
rostopic list lists the topics, rostopic hz $topic echoes
the propper data.
PROBLEM:
On the local client machine, rostopic list works propberly.
rostopic hz $topic seems to connect, but it only writes
no new messages.
QUESTION:
What needs to be done and how can this be done. I imagine to
tunnel all ephemeral ports (37268-61000) from the Server to
the Client. Would this help? How can this be done without
changing .ssh/config?
